# "Configure your browser for visual effects" error on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking to get visual effects working in chrome in google meet, i have the "configure your browser for visual effects" message in meet. Hardware accelleration is toggled on in chrome settings.

I have reset all flags in `chrome://flags/` and still have the issue, please help - i work from a bedroom!

from `chrome://gpu/` (have had to reduce size for the question).

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
OpenGL: Disabled
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Raw Draw: Disabled
Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL2: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGPU: Disabled
Problems Detected
WebGPU has been disabled via blocklist or the command line.
Disabled Features: webgpu
Accelerated video encode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line.
Disabled Features: video_encode
Gpu compositing has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line. The browser will fall back to software compositing and hardware acceleration will be unavailable.
Disabled Features: gpu_compositing
ANGLE Features
allowCompressedFormats (Frontend workarounds): Enabled: true
Allow compressed formats
cacheCompiledShader (Frontend features) anglebug:7036: Enabled: true
Enable to cache compiled shaders
disableAnisotropicFiltering (Frontend workarounds): Disabled
Disable support for anisotropic filtering
disableDrawBuffersIndexed (Frontend features) anglebug:7724: Disabled
Disable support for OES_draw_buffers_indexed and EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
disableProgramBinary (Frontend features) anglebug:5007: Disabled
Disable support for GL_OES_get_program_binary
disableProgramCaching (Frontend features) anglebug:1423136: Disabled
Disables saving programs to the cache
disableProgramCachingForTransformFeedback (Frontend workarounds): Disabled
On some GPUs, program binaries don't contain transform feedback varyings
dumpShaderSource (Frontend features) anglebug:7760: Disabled
Write shader source to temp directory
emulatePixelLocalStorage (Frontend features) anglebug:7279: Enabled: true
Emulate ANGLE_shader_pixel_local_storage using shader images
enableCaptureLimits (Frontend features) anglebug:5750: Disabled
Set the context limits like frame capturing was enabled
enableProgramBinaryForCapture (Frontend features) anglebug:5658: Disabled
Even if FrameCapture is enabled, enable GL_OES_get_program_binary
enableShaderSubstitution (Frontend workarounds) anglebug:7761: Disabled
Check the filesystem for shaders to use instead of those provided through glShaderSource
forceDepthAttachmentInitOnClear (Frontend workarounds) anglebug:7246: Disabled
Force depth attachment initialization on clear ops
forceGlErrorChecking (Frontend features) https://issuetracker.google.com/220069903: Disabled: (IsAndroid() && isSwiftShader)
Force GL error checking (i.e. prevent applications from disabling error checking
forceInitShaderVariables (Frontend features): Disabled
Force-enable shader variable initialization
forceRobustResourceInit (Frontend features) anglebug:6041: Disabled
Force-enable robust resource init
loseContextOnOutOfMemory (Frontend workarounds): Enabled: true
Some users rely on a lost context notification if a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error occurs
scalarizeVecAndMatConstructorArgs (Frontend workarounds) 1165751: Disabled: false
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent
singleThreadedTextureDecompression (Frontend workarounds): Disabled
Disables multi-threaded decompression of compressed texture formats
allocateNonZeroMemory (Vulkan features) anglebug:4384: Disabled: false
Fill new allocations with non-zero values to flush out errors.
allowGenerateMipmapWithCompute (Vulkan features) anglebug:4551: Disabled: supportsSubgroupQuadOpsInComputeShader && mSubgroupExtendedTypesFeatures.shaderSubgroupExtendedTypes && maxComputeWorkGroupInvocations >= 256 && ((isAMD && !IsWindows()) || isNvidia || isSamsung)
Use the compute path to generate mipmaps on devices that meet the minimum requirements, and the performance is better.
appendAliasedMemoryDecorationsToSsbo (Vulkan workarounds) b/266235549: Disabled: isARM && armDriverVersion >= ARMDriverVersion(38, 1, 0)
Append aliased memory decoration to ssbo in SpirV if the ssbo in GLSL is not declared with restrict memory qualifier
asyncCommandBufferReset (Vulkan features) https://issuetracker.google.com/255411748: Enabled: true
Reset command buffer in async thread.
asyncCommandQueue (Vulkan features) anglebug:4324: Disabled: false
Use CommandQueue worker thread to dispatch work to GPU.
bottomLeftOriginPresentRegionRectangles (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled: IsAndroid()
On some platforms present region rectangles are expected to have a bottom-left origin, instead of top-left origin as from spec
bresenhamLineRasterization (Vulkan features): Enabled: mLineRasterizationFeatures.bresenhamLines == 1U
Enable Bresenham line rasterization via VK_EXT_line_rasterization extension
clampPointSize (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:2970: Disabled: isNvidia && nvidiaVersion.major < uint32_t(IsWindows() ? 430 : 421)
The point size range reported from the API is inconsistent with the actual behavior
compressVertexData (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Compress vertex data to smaller data types when possible. Using this feature makes ANGLE non-conformant.
deferFlushUntilEndRenderPass (Vulkan workarounds) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166475273: Enabled: !isQualcommProprietary
Allow glFlush to be deferred until renderpass ends
depthClamping (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:3970: Disabled: isNvidia && mPhysicalDeviceFeatures.depthClamp && mFeatures.supportsDepthClipEnable.enabled && (!IsLinux() || nvidiaVersion.major > 418u)
The depth value is not clamped to [0,1] for floating point depth buffers.
disableFlippingBlitWithCommand (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:3498: Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcommProprietary
vkCmdBlitImage with flipped coordinates blits incorrectly.
disallowMixedDepthStencilLoadOpNoneAndLoad (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:7370: Disabled: isARM && armDriverVersion < ARMDriverVersion(38, 1, 0)
Disallow use of LOAD_OP_NONE for only one of the depth or stencil aspects of a depth/stencil attachment
doubleDepthBiasConstantFactor (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled: isIntel && !IsWindows()
Due to a Vulkan spec ambiguity, some drivers interpret depthBiasConstantFactor as half the expected value
eglColorspaceAttributePassthrough (Vulkan features) anglebug:7319: Disabled: IsAndroid() && isSamsung
Support passthrough of EGL colorspace attribute values
emulateAdvancedBlendEquations (Vulkan features) anglebug:3586: Disabled: !mFeatures.supportsBlendOperationAdvanced.enabled && (isVenus || !isIntel)
Emulate GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
emulateDithering (Vulkan features) anglebug:6755: Disabled: IsAndroid()
Emulate OpenGL dithering
emulateR32fImageAtomicExchange (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:5535: Enabled: true
Emulate r32f images with r32ui to support imageAtomicExchange.
emulateTransformFeedback (Vulkan features) anglebug:3205: Enabled: (!mFeatures.supportsTransformFeedbackExtension.enabled && mPhysicalDeviceFeatures.vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics == 1U)
Emulate transform feedback as the VK_EXT_transform_feedback is not present.
emulatedPrerotation180 (Vulkan features) anglebug:4901: Disabled
Emulate 180-degree prerotation.
emulatedPrerotation270 (Vulkan features) anglebug:4901: Disabled
Emulate 270-degree prerotation.
emulatedPrerotation90 (Vulkan features) anglebug:4901: Disabled
Emulate 90-degree prerotation.
enableAsyncPipelineCacheCompression (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:4722: Disabled: isVenus
Enable compressing pipeline cache in a thread.
enableMultisampledRenderToTexture (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:4937: Disabled: mFeatures.supportsMultisampledRenderToSingleSampled.enabled || mFeatures.supportsMultisampledRenderToSingleSampledGOOGLEX.enabled || (supportsIndependentDepthStencilResolve && (isTileBasedRenderer || isSamsung))
Expose EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture
enablePreRotateSurfaces (Vulkan features) anglebug:3502: Disabled: IsAndroid() && supportsNegativeViewport
Enable Android pre-rotation for landscape applications
enablePrecisionQualifiers (Vulkan features) anglebug:3078: Enabled: !(IsPixel2(mPhysicalDeviceProperties.vendorID, mPhysicalDeviceProperties.deviceID) && (mPhysicalDeviceProperties.driverVersion < kPixel2DriverWithRelaxedPrecision)) && !IsPixel4(mPhysicalDeviceProperties.vendorID, mPhysicalDeviceProperties.deviceID)
Enable precision qualifiers in shaders
explicitlyCastMediumpFloatTo16Bit (Vulkan workarounds) https://issuetracker.google.com/274859104: Disabled: isARM
Explicitly cast mediump floating point values to 16 bit
explicitlyEnablePerSampleShading (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:6876: Disabled: isARM
Explicitly enable per-sample shading if the fragment shader contains the sample qualifier
exposeNonConformantExtensionsAndVersions (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:5375: Disabled: kExposeNonConformantExtensionsAndVersions && !isVenus
Expose GLES versions and extensions that are not conformant.
forceContinuousRefreshOnSharedPresent (Vulkan features) https://issuetracker.google.com/229267970: Disabled: false
Force to create vulkan swapchain with continuous refresh on shared present
forceD16TexFilter (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:3452: Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcommProprietary
VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM does not support VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT, which prevents OES_depth_texture from being supported.
forceFallbackFormat (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Force a fallback format for angle_end2end_tests
forceFragmentShaderPrecisionHighpToMediump (Vulkan workarounds) https://issuetracker.google.com/184850002: Disabled: false
Forces highp precision in fragment shader to mediump.
forceMaxUniformBufferSize16KB (Vulkan workarounds) https://issuetracker.google.com/161903006: Disabled: isQualcommProprietary && isAdreno540
Force max uniform buffer size to 16K on some device due to bug
forceNearestFiltering (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Force nearest filtering when sampling.
forceNearestMipFiltering (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Force nearest mip filtering when sampling.
forceStaticPrimitiveRestartState (Vulkan workarounds) https://issuetracker.google.com/275210062: Disabled: mFeatures.supportsExtendedDynamicState2.enabled && isARM
Force static state for VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_ENABLE due to driver bugs
forceStaticVertexStrideState (Vulkan workarounds) https://bugs.fuchsia.dev/p/fuchsia/issues/detail?id=107106: Disabled: mFeatures.supportsExtendedDynamicState.enabled && isARM
Force static state for VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VERTEX_INPUT_BINDING_STRIDE_EXT due to driver bugs
forceSubmitImmutableTextureUpdates (Vulkan app workarounds) anglebug:6929: Disabled
Force submit updates to immutable textures
forceTextureLodOffset1 (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Increase the minimum texture level-of-detail by 1 when sampling.
forceTextureLodOffset2 (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Increase the minimum texture level-of-detail by 2 when sampling.
forceTextureLodOffset3 (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Increase the minimum texture level-of-detail by 3 when sampling.
forceTextureLodOffset4 (Vulkan workarounds): Disabled
Increase the minimum texture level-of-detail by 4 when sampling.
forceWaitForSubmissionToCompleteForQueryResult (Vulkan workarounds) https://issuetracker.google.com/253522366: Disabled: isARM || (isNvidia && nvidiaVersion.major < 470u)
Force wait for submission to complete before calling getQueryResult(wait).
hasEffectivePipelineCacheSerialization (Vulkan features) anglebug:7369: Disabled: !isSwiftShader
Whether the implementation serializes the Vulkan pipeline cache effectively. On some implementations, pipeline cache serialization returns no data, so there is no benefit to serializing it
logMemoryReportCallbacks (Vulkan features): Disabled: false
Log each callback from VK_EXT_device_memory_report
logMemoryReportStats (Vulkan features): Disabled: false
Log stats from VK_EXT_device_memory_report each swap
mapUnspecifiedColorSpaceToPassThrough (Vulkan features): Disabled: isVenus
Use VK_COLOR_SPACE_PASS_THROUGH_EXT for EGL_NONE or unspecifed color spaces
mergeProgramPipelineCachesToGlobalCache (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:7369: Enabled: !mFeatures.supportsGraphicsPipelineLibrary.enabled || (mFeatures.preferMonolithicPipelinesOverLibraries.enabled && libraryBlobsAreReusedByMonolithicPipelines)
Whether it's beneficial to merge the pipeline cache for the shaders subset of the pipeline into the monolithic pipeline cache. Only useful on platforms where monolithic pipelines can reuse blobs from partial pipelines
mutableMipmapTextureUpload (Vulkan features) anglebug:7308: Enabled: !(IsWindows() && isIntel)
Enable uploading the previously defined mutable mipmap texture.
overrideSurfaceFormatRGB8ToRGBA8 (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:6651: Enabled: true
Override surface format GL_RGB8 to GL_RGBA8
padBuffersToMaxVertexAttribStride (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:4428: Disabled: isAMD || isSamsung
Vulkan considers vertex attribute accesses to count up to the last multiple of the stride. This additional access supports AMD's robust buffer access implementation. AMDVLK in particular will return incorrect values when the vertex access extends into the range that would be the stride padding and the buffer is too small. This workaround limits GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_STRIDE to a maximum value and pads up every buffer allocation size to be a multiple of the maximum stride.
perFrameWindowSizeQuery (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:3623: Disabled: IsAndroid() || isIntel || (IsWindows() && isAMD) || IsFuchsia() || isSamsung || displayVk->isWayland()
Vulkan swapchain is not returning VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE when window resizing
permanentlySwitchToFramebufferFetchMode (Vulkan features): Disabled: isTileBasedRenderer
Whether the context should permanently switch to framebuffer fetch mode on first encounter
persistentlyMappedBuffers (Vulkan features) anglebug:2162: Enabled: true
Persistently map buffer memory to reduce map/unmap IOCTL overhead.
preferAggregateBarrierCalls (Vulkan workarounds) anglebug:4633: Enabled: isImmediateModeRenderer
Single barrier call is preferred over multiple calls with fine grained pipeline stage dependency information
preferCPUForBufferSubData (Vulkan features) http://issuetracker.google.com/200067929: Disabled: isARM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling this setting fixed the issue, but am not sure it if is the right solution - interested in getting a better solution if there is one.

[image]